# Using a single fold_left to find both length and sum of a list

Tags: ocaml

I have been trying to wrap my head around `fold_left` and `fold_right`. As practice, I have been trying to rewrite a lot of functions in `fold_left` and `fold_right` to strengthen my knowledge. For instance, in finding the average of a list, I would calculate the sum and the length of the list using folds.

```
let sum_l xs = List.fold_left (fun x y -> x + y) 0 xs;;
let len_l xs = List.fold_left (fun x _ -> x + 1) 0 xs;;
```

And then I would move on to find the average. Here is my question. Is it possible to both these values in one single `fold_left`? How should I write the anonymous function? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to use a pair as your accumulator:

```
# let sum_and_len xs = List.fold_left (fun (s,l) x -> s+x, l+1) (0,0) xs;;
val sum_and_len : int list -> int * int = <fun>
# sum_and_len [0;1;2;3];;
- : int * int = (6, 4)
```